# Qt plugin error at application startup Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation, qt5, 20.04

Good day.
When starting a new application (the installation was successful without any errors) on Ubuntu 20.04, the program starts with an error -

```
  ~$ openscada 2020-04-19T00:58:25 1[/] Primary Station: Download. 2020-04-19T00:58:25 1[/sub_BD/] Project initial > Databases:
> Connecting the module 'SQLite'. 2020-04-19T00:58:25 1[/sub_BD/]
> Project initial > Databases: Connecting the module 'DBF'.
> 2020-04-19T00:58:25 1[/sub_DAQ/] Project initial > Data Collection:
> Module Connection 'JavaLikeCalc'. 2020-04-19T00:58:25 1[/sub_DAQ/]
> Project initial > Data Collection: Module Connection 'LogicLev'.
> 2020-04-19T00:58:25 1[/sub_Transport/] Project initial > Transports:
> Module Connection 'Sockets'. 2020-04-19T00:58:25 1[/sub_Transport/]
> Project initial > Transports: Module Connection 'Serial'.
> 2020-04-19T00:58:25 1[/sub_Protocol/] Project initial > Transport
> Protocols: Module Connection 'SelfSystem'. 2020-04-19T00:58:25
> 1[/sub_Protocol/] Project initial > Transport Protocols: Module
> Connection 'UserProtocol'. 2020-04-19T00:58:25 1[/sub_Special/]
> Project initial > Special: Module Connection 'FLibSYS'.
> 2020-04-19T00:58:25 1[/sub_Special/] Project initial > Special: Module
> Connection 'FLibComplex1'. 2020-04-19T00:58:25 1[/sub_UI/] Project
> initial > User Interfaces: Module Connection 'QTStarter'.
> QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path
> "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms" ...
> QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at
> "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so" Found
> metadata in lib
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so,
> metadata= {
>     "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
>     "MetaData": {
>         "Keys": [
>             "eglfs"
>         ]
>     },
>     "archreq": 0,
>     "className": "QEglFSIntegrationPlugin",
>     "debug": false,
>     "version": 330752 }
>     Got keys from plugin meta data ("eglfs") QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at
> "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so" Found
> metadata in lib
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so,
> metadata= {
>     "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
>     "MetaData": {
>         "Keys": [
>             "linuxfb"
>         ]
>     },
>     "archreq": 0,
>     "className": "QLinuxFbIntegrationPlugin",
>     "debug": false,
>     "version": 330752 }
>     Got keys from plugin meta data ("linuxfb") QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at
> "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so" Found
> metadata in lib
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so,
> metadata= {
>     "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
>     "MetaData": {
>         "Keys": [
>             "minimal"
>         ]
>     },
>     "archreq": 0,
>     "className": "QMinimalIntegrationPlugin",
>     "debug": false,
>     "version": 330752 }
>     Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimal") QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at
> "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so"
> Found metadata in lib
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so,
> metadata= {
>     "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
>     "MetaData": {
>         "Keys": [
>             "minimalegl"
>         ]
>     },
>     "archreq": 0,
>     "className": "QMinimalEglIntegrationPlugin",
>     "debug": false,
>     "version": 330752 }
>     Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimalegl") QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at
> "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so"
> Found metadata in lib
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so,
> metadata= {
>     "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
>     "MetaData": {
>         "Keys": [
>             "offscreen"
>         ]
>     },
>     "archreq": 0,
>     "className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
>     "debug": false,
>     "version": 330752 }
>     Got keys from plugin meta data ("offscreen") QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at
> "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so" Found
> metadata in lib
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so, metadata=
> {
>     "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
>     "MetaData": {
>         "Keys": [
>             "vnc"
>         ]
>     },
>     "archreq": 0,
>     "className": "QVncIntegrationPlugin",
>     "debug": false,
>     "version": 330752 }
>     Got keys from plugin meta data ("vnc") QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at
> "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so" Found
> metadata in lib
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
> {
>     "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
>     "MetaData": {
>         "Keys": [
>             "xcb"
>         ]
>     },
>     "archreq": 0,
>     "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
>     "debug": false,
>     "version": 330752 }
>     Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb") Cannot load library /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so:
> (/opt/Qt/lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5: undefined symbol:
> _ZN20QEventDispatcherUNIX6selectEiP6fd_setS1_S1_P8timespec) QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on
> "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so" : "Cannot
> load library
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so:
> (/opt/Qt/lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5: undefined symbol:
> _ZN20QEventDispatcherUNIX6selectEiP6fd_setS1_S1_P8timespec)" This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt
> platform plugin "xcb".   Available platform plugins are: eglfs,
> linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.   Reinstalling the
> application may fix this problem.
```

This application on Ubuntu 18.04.01 - started and worked without problems.
Reinstalling the application on Ubuntu 20.04 does not help.
Although the Qt library file libqxcb.so at the specified path /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so is present.
Please tell me what can be done to fix the error.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *focal fossa* [20.04] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 20.04 is 23rd April 2020 when your question will be on-topic here).

Comment: If you're helping to test the development release (*focal fossa* isn't 20.04 until release time), then you can also use #ubuntu-quality via IRC or telegram, however general support should still go to #ubuntu+1 sites until *focal fossa* has been released and reached stable 20.04).  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs